# Slide out text from behind navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly let me say I'm starting to realize I need to learn jQuery, and while I'm here asking for help, this weekend I'm going to hit the Treehouse jQuery videos hard.

I'd like a little help with an effect I'm trying to create with a navigation menu please, if you take a look at the fiddle I've made:
http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/kvMkF/4/

As you can see there's a list of navigation links and over them is the text corresponding to the link. What I'd like is for that text to initially not be view-able to anyone except screen readers, and when a user mouse-over's a link the corresponding text slides from behind the leftmost list item into visibility, and the text that says "NAVIGATE" disappears. I'd like all of the text to slide from where it is initially and to the same place, where the "NAVIGATE" text is.

I'm open to the solution being only CSS (don't think its possible with only CSS), jQuery or JavaScript.

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'll make sure to start learning jQuery as soon as I can.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <p class="nav-hvr-init">Navigate</p>
    <ul> <!-- no closing tag on <li> so that the whitespace between elements is removed-->
        <li id="about-us">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text">about us</span>
        <li id="products">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text">products</span>
        <li id="the-team">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text">the team</span>
        <li id="environment">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text">environment</span>
        <li id="contact">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text">contact</span>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-row {
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
}

#nav-col {
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: #336600;
}

.main-nav {
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #336600;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#about-us {
  background: #66CC66 url('http://s10.postimg.org/xqx00ofzp/about_us.png') no-repeat center;
}

#about-us:hover {
  background: #66CC66 url('http://s10.postimg.org/9borzmh2t/about_us_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#about-us:active {
  background: #66CC66 url('http://s10.postimg.org/ekjsxhzhx/about_us_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}

#products {
  background: #33CC33 url('http://s10.postimg.org/defsypb79/products.png') no-repeat center;
}

#products:hover {
  background: #33CC33 url('http://s10.postimg.org/y2j1r6lth/products_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#products:active {
  background: #33CC33 url('http://s10.postimg.org/6p99iopv9/products_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}

#the-team {
  background: #339900 url('http://s10.postimg.org/4sh4ruol1/the_team.png') no-repeat center;
}

#the-team:hover {
  background: #339900 url('http://s10.postimg.org/buf2e1s6t/the_team_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#the-team:active {
  background: #339900 url('http://s10.postimg.org/wd9yj4645/the_team_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}

#environment {
  background: #006600 url('http://s10.postimg.org/gb7fcq6et/environment.png') no-repeat center;
}

#environment:hover {
  background: #006600 url('http://s10.postimg.org/n47s8zx85/environment_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#environment:active {
  background: #006600 url('http://s10.postimg.org/6y6u8m2np/environment_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}

#contact {
  background: #003300 url('http://s10.postimg.org/9pq3z816d/contact.png') no-repeat center;
}

#contact:hover {
  background: #003300 url('http://s10.postimg.org/udordymet/contact_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#contact:active {
  background: #003300 url('http://s10.postimg.org/4scje3z79/contact_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav > ul {
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  padding: 0;
}

li > svg {
  margin: 9% 0 0 11%;
}

li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 0;
  height: 56px;
}

.nav-text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
  font-size: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nav-hvr-init {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
  font-size: 21px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 280px;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.txt-arrows {
  font-family: 'Arrows';
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that? Is this what you wanted?

I also added `sr-only` class (from Bootstrap).

http://jsfiddle.net/kvMkF/8/

```
$( ".nav-link" ).hover(
    function() {
    var text = $( this ).siblings( "span" ).html();   
          $(".nav-hvr-init")
          .stop()
          .animate({right: '0px'},200,function() {
              $(this).html(text).animate({right:'280px'},200);
          });
  }, function() {
      $(".nav-hvr-init")
            .stop()
            .animate({right: '0px'},200,function() {
                $(this).html('Navigate').animate({right:'280px'},200);
            });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy.

jQuery:

```
$( ".nav-link" ).hover(
  function() {
    var ntext = $( this ).siblings( "span" ).html();
    $( ".nav-hvr-init" ).html( ntext );
  }, function() {
    $( ".nav-hvr-init" ).html( "Navigate" );
  }
);
```

Also added `display: none;` to `.nav-text`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobthyasian/kvMkF/6/)

Comment: Brilliant, that's almost how I want it. Can you make it so that the text slides out from the right, so it looks like it comes from behind the from behind the icon with an i in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".main-nav li").hover(function(){
  $(".nav-hvr-init").fadeOut();
    $(this).find('.nav-text').show().animate({left : '150px'});
  }, function(){
  $(".nav-hvr-init").fadeIn();
    $(this).find('.nav-text').animate({left : '-100%'});
});
```

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/2rcGX/)